# How to search and install package in Anaconda (Conda)

Tags: installation, python, packages, ipython, anaconda

I am trying to install `pandoc` so I did `conda install pandoc` but nothing popped up and it told me to search.  I searched with `anaconda search -t conda pandoc` and the results are below...How can I install `zhenxieit/pandoc`? I'm trying to install it to make .pdf files from my `iPython` documents so I think that's the best one.  I tried `conda install zhenxieit/pandoc` but that didn't work and then I tried `conda install --name zhenxieit/pandoc` and no cigar.

```
Using binstar api site https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms      
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
     ???/pandoc                |   1.12.3 | conda           | linux-64       
     BjornFJohansson/pandocfilters |    1.2.4 | conda           | linux-64, win-32, osx-64, linux-32, win-64
                                          : Utilities for writing pandoc filters in python
     asmeurer/pandoc           |   1.13.1 | conda           | linux-64, linux-32, osx-64
                                          : Universal markup converter
     auto/flask-flatpages-pandoc |      0.2 | conda           | linux-64, linux-32
                                          : http://github.com/fhirschmann/Flask-FlatPages-Pandoc
     auto/pypandoc             |    0.8.1 | conda           | linux-64, linux-32
                                          : https://github.com/bebraw/pypandoc
     ivoflipse/pandocfilters   |    1.2.3 | conda           | win-64         
                                          : Utilities for writing pandoc filters in python
     jsw-fnal/pandoc           | 1.12.4.2 | conda           | linux-64       
                                          : None
     richlewis/pandoc          |   1.12.3 | conda           | osx-64         
                                          : Universal markup converter
     wakari1/pandoc            |   1.12.3 | conda           | linux-64       
                                          : Universal markup converter
     zhenxieit/pandoc          |   1.13.1 | conda           | osx-64         
                                          : Universal markup converter
```

Answer (score 5):

rka

you can find a website to each user package combination. You asked for pandoc from zhenxieit's repository. You can find it on [https://anaconda.org/zhenxieit/pandoc] how to install it. This specific package installs with

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/zhenxieit pandoc
```

Answer (score 0):

With the updates over the past two years, you can now install `pandoc` using the `conda install` command you originally tried.  Here is the output I just received on my Windows machine.

```
$ conda install pandoc
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\schowell\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - pandoc


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-4.5.4                |           py36_0         1.0 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    pandoc: 1.19.2.1-hb2460c7_1

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:  4.5.2-py36_0        --> 4.5.4-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)?


Downloading and Extracting Packages
conda 4.5.4########## | 100%
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
```